# How to delete program installed with .bundle?

Tags: 12.04, vmware

Recently i install vmware 4.1 (which is bundle file). Now i want to remove it. How to do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

VMware comes with a shell script named as `.bundle`. With this script all applications bundled with VMware will be installed. Unless a package manager is called from this script (which isn't) it will be done without the help of a package manager. Therefore our package managers can not help uninstalling the software.

However the installer that comes with VMware (vmware-installer) should have an option to uninstall components:

```
vmware-installer -h
```

To display all options you have with this program. Whether this will work, and if really all packages can be removed by this I don't know.

An example of how to remove the vmware-player is given at the [Ubuntu Community Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware/Player):

```
sudo vmware-installer -u vmware-player
```

Also given there is a long list of things to do for a manual uninstall in case this fails.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to remove VMware completely, you can try this (First make sure the `.bundle` file is executable.)

```
./VMware.bundle -u"vmware-workstation"
```

For making a file executable :

```
 chmod +x /path/to/the/file
```

And, even without that - and from any directory (in modern times) you can run:

```
 sudo vmware-installer -u vmware-workstation
```

And that will uninstall it.